# How can I send a notification to an endpoint when a Throttler starts/stops throttling?

Tags: apache-camel

As the title says, I would like to send a notification to an endpoint if messages to it start getting throttled, and another message when the throttling stops.

I currently have the following (very basic) route configuration:

```
from("test-jms:queue:test.queue")
.throttle(2)
.to("file://test");
```

This configuration throttles messages just fine, but I need a way to let the consumer know that the messages are being throttled.

When the Throttler starts throttling, I would like to send a notification to the 'to' endpoint so those reading the messages know that they are being throttled. I would also like to be able to send another message when the Throttler is no longer throttling, so the consumer knows the messages are up to date.

This doesn't appear to be something the Throttler does. The only way I see of getting a notification when it starts throttling is setting `rejectExecution` to true, at which point it will throw an exception. The problem is that execution stops at that point, and no more messages are passed through (since an exception was thrown).

My current thoughts are that I will need to create a custom bean/processor/something that performs essentially the same function as the Throttler, but also injects a message when the throttling starts or stops. I don't want to do that unless I really need to, though. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No the throttler eip does not support such information (however you may be able to grab some statistics via JMX). A different thought would be to reverse the direction so the consumers signals upstream when they want new messages (this is what reactive systems does).

I assume the above to write to a file is just some example, what consumers are you using in real life, and do they really need to know that some messages are backed up within a short-time period of 1 second because they are throttled? Also since your source is JMS, you can also look at the route throttling policy, where you can suspend/resume the JMS consumer instead of using the throttler EIP.

Comment: You are correct that writing to file is just an example. Additionally, the messages are coming from an AMQP endpoint, not JMS. The example I gave was based on http://camel.apache.org/walk-through-an-example.html. The software will essentially be transforming and then forwarding messages it receives to a chat client. The reason I want to send a notification message is that there's a chance messages will pile up while the first few are being throttled (the producer can occasionally produce hundreds of messages per second, which overwhelms the chat client).